# How to create SOAP API in Magento2?

Tags: soap, php-5.4, rest-api, magento2-dev-beta

Today i have created **Magento2 REST API**, it's working. similarly how to create soap api in magento2?.

**app/etc/config.php**

```
'modules' => 
  array (  
    'Learning_CalculatorWebService' => 1,
  ),
```

**app/code/Learning/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Learning_CalculatorWebService" schema_version="2.0.0"/>
</config>
```

**app/code/Learning\CalculatorWebService\Api**

```
<?php

namespace Learning\CalculatorWebService\Api;

interface CalculatorInterface
{
    public function add($num1, $num2);
}
```

**app/code/Learning/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Learning\CalculatorWebService\Api\CalculatorInterface" type="Learning\CalculatorWebService\Model\Calculator" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Learning/etc/webapi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../app/code/Magento/Webapi/etc/webapi.xsd">


    <route url="/V1/calculator/add/:num1/:num2" method="GET">
        <service class="Learning\CalculatorWebService\Api\CalculatorInterface" method="add"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>

</routes>
```

**app/code/Learning\CalculatorWebService\Model**

```
<?php
namespace Learning\CalculatorWebService\Model;
use Learning\CalculatorWebService\Api\CalculatorInterface;

class Calculator implements CalculatorInterface
{
    public function add($num1, $num2) {
        return $num1 + $num2;
    }

}
```

And i have entered url http://192.168.0.52/magento-2/index.php/rest/V1/calculator/add/1/2

it's returning 3 working fine.

Similarly how to create **Magento2 SOAP API**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have acieved to debug `getServiceMetadata()` function from `root/app/code/Magento/Webapi/Model/Soap/Config.php`.

```
/**
     * Retrieve specific service interface data.
     *
     * @param string $serviceName
     * @return array
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     */
    public function getServiceMetadata($serviceName)
    {
        $soapServicesConfig = $this->getSoapServicesConfig();
        \Zend_Debug::dump($soapServicesConfig); exit;
        if (!isset($soapServicesConfig[$serviceName]) || !is_array($soapServicesConfig[$serviceName])) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(__('Requested service is not available: "%1"', $serviceName));
        }
        return $soapServicesConfig[$serviceName];
    }
```

After writing debug code from above method enter your webservice url from your browser like say `http://192.168.0.183/NewMagento2/soap?wsdl&services=customerCustomerRepositoryV1` it will form a wsdl webservices. From this we can find core & custom webservices names.

more information look on [Branko Article](http://foggyline.net/getting-the-list-of-all-magento-2-soap-services/).

Comment: I tried the same but it failed with error. `Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] SoapServer::SoapServer(): Invalid parameters`

Comment: @magento two: Can you please share your code for Soap connection in M2 custom module if possible.

Comment: @PurushotamSharma You mean code for invoking Soap API in M2?

Comment: Yes, I also want to establish soap connection in my custom M2 module

Comment: @PurushotamSharma Create a thread and tag me.

Comment: can I create a thread on Github?

Comment: @PurushotamSharma https://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @magento two:  Please find here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205432/create-soap-connection-in-magento-custom-module
Please let me know if you want any.

Comment: "Branko Article" not found 404. Don't insert links. They usually are going to become dead.

Answer (score 1):

```
        $token = 'your-access-token';

        require('vendor/zendframework/zend-server/src/Client.php');
        require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php');
        require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php');

        $opts = ['http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Bearer " . $token]];

        $context = stream_context_create($opts);


        $wsdlUrl = YOUR_BASEURL."soap?wsdl&services=learningCalculatorWebServiceCalculatorV1";
        $addArgs = array('num1'=>2, 'num2'=>1);
        $sumArgs = array('nums'=>array(2,1000));

        try{
            $soapClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlUrl);
            $soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);
            $soapClient->setStreamContext($context);

            $soapResponse = $soapClient->learningCalculatorWebServiceCalculatorV1Add($addArgs);
            print_r($soapResponse);//3

            $soapResponse = $soapClient->learningCalculatorWebServiceCalculatorV1Sum($sumArgs);//1002
            print_r($soapResponse);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo 'Error : '.$e->getMessage();
        }
```

Comment: It does not work and return this error `Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] SoapServer::SoapServer(): Invalid parameters`

Answer (score 0):

To create soap api call to get product from sku using magento 2 default API service :

```
$request = new SoapClient('http://192.168.0.54/magento20sample/index.php/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogProductRepositoryV1',
            array(
                'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
                'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array('http'=> array('header' => 'Authorization: Bearer w9vqx2uyenkbvbim6mwochwapq714yox')
                    )                               
                )
            )
        );
        $response = $request->catalogProductRepositoryV1Get(array('sku'=>'test'));
```

If you want to make full costume module for API in magento 2 refer this : https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/magento-2-developers/9781785886584/ch09s08.html#ch09lvl3sec14