# Magento2 : Create SOAP connection in magento custom module

Tags: magento2, module, custom, soap

I am using below code in M1 to establish the connection using SOAP:-

```
<?php

    class Company_Module_Helper_Webservice extends Company_Module_Helper_Basehelper
    {   
        private function Connect()
        {
            $WebserviceUrl = Mage::helper('module/systemvalues')->getSysValue('web_service_url');
            return new SoapClient($WebserviceUrl, array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
        }
    }
```

Now I want to establish SOAP connection in M2:-

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Helper;

class Webservice extends \Company\Module\Helper\Basehelper
{

    /**
     * @var \Company\Module\Helper\Systemvalues
     */
    protected $moduleSystemvaluesHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Company\Module\Helper\Systemvalues $moduleSystemvaluesHelper
    ) {
        $this->moduleSystemvaluesHelper = $moduleSystemvaluesHelper;
    }
    public function Connect()
    {
        $WebserviceUrl = $this->moduleSystemvaluesHelper->getSysValue('web_service_url');
        $logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
        $logger->debug($WebserviceUrl);
        /** below line work in M1, now I want write code for M2 to estibalsed the soap connection for my module  */
        return new SoapClient($WebserviceUrl, array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spent lot of time on this issue we found below solution, my that help you:-

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Helper;

class Webservice extends \Company\Module\Helper\Basehelper
{

    /**
     * @var \Company\Module\Helper\Systemvalues
     */
    protected $moduleSystemvaluesHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Company\Module\Helper\Systemvalues $moduleSystemvaluesHelper
    ) {
        $this->moduleSystemvaluesHelper = $moduleSystemvaluesHelper;
    }
    public function Connect()
    {
        $WebserviceUrl = $this->khaosconnectSystemvaluesHelper->getSysValue('web_service_url');

        $trace = true;
        $exceptions = false;

        $opts = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false,));

        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $soapClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client($WebserviceUrl);
        $soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);
        $soapClient->setStreamContext($context);        
        return $soapClient;
    }
}
```

and use connect function to access the api function as below:-

```
public function getSites()
{
    $client = $this->Connect();
    return $client->APIFunction(array('' => ''));        
}
```